# runtime error '-2147217900' (80040e14)': automation error using where in the sql query from excel vba

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I am trying to connect to my sqlserver express 2005 from excel vba using the following (copied from some forum routine as i am not very into databases). It works perfect. As soon as I use WHERE in the sqlquery variable (already verified quotes double and single) i get

runtime error '-2147217900' (80040e14)':
automation error

Similar routine that work pulling data from other people same thing. I appreciate deeply your help

Thanks

Sub ConnectTEST()

```
' Create a connection object.
Dim cnPubs As ADODB.Connection
Set cnPubs = New ADODB.Connection
Dim sqlquery As String
Dim rsPubs As ADODB.Recordset
Set rsPubs = New ADODB.Recordset

' Provide the connection string.
Dim strConn As String

'Use the SQL Server OLE DB Provider.
strConn = "PROVIDER=SQLOLEDB;"

sqlquery = "SELECT * FROM [Logisuite].[dbo].[EoWebStatus]"

'Connect to the Pubs database on the local server.
strConn = strConn & "Server=SERVITRANSMAIn\SQLEXPRESS;Database=logisuite;Trusted_Connection=True;"

'Use an integrated login.
strConn = strConn & "INTEGRATED SECURITY=sspi;"

'Now open the connection.
cnPubs.Open strConn

' Create a recordset object.
Set rsPubs = New ADODB.Recordset

With rsPubs
    ' Assign the Connection object.
    .ActiveConnection = cnPubs
    ' Extract the required records.
    .Open sqlquery
    ' Copy the records into cell A1 on Sheet1.
    Sheet1.Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset rsPubs

    ' Tidy up
    .Close
End With

cnPubs.Close
Set rsPubs = Nothing
Set cnPubs = Nothing
```

End Sub

Comment: Show the code that **doesn't** work, and indicate which line causes the error.

Comment: I am 99% sure its the query that's causing the automation error. Show your `WHERE` query!

Comment: Guys A Million thanks for answering   the complete query follows:     sqlquery = "SELECT * FROM [Logisuite].[dbo].[EoWebStatus]" & _
    " WHERE [UpdateBy] = " & Chr$(39) & "dennisk" & Chr$(39)    and the line that brings the error is   .open sqlquery  inside the with-end with

Comment: to complement my previous post when i am printing the sqlquery variable in the immediate window the output is the following:        SELECT * FROM [Logisuite].[dbo].[EoWebStatus] WHERE [UpdateBy] = 'dennisk'      which apparently is the correct one.

Comment: and give a second complement i cannot use even an order by..... nothgin except the mere select from thing

Comment: i got the answer on my own... thanks anyway

Comment: what is the answer ?